# SQL Access INSERT INTO fails

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to make a visual basic application which is connected to a Microsoft Access Database using OLEDB. Inside my database I have a user table with the following layout

```
ID - Autonumber
Username - Text
Password - Text
Email - Text
```

To insert data into the table I use the following query

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Email) 
VALUES ('004606', 'Password', 'Email@Mail.com')
```

However I seem to get an error with this statement and according to VB it's a syntax error.

But then I tried to use the following query

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username) Values ('004606')
```

This query seemed to work absolutely fine...

So the problem is I can insert into just one field but not all 3 (excluding the ID field because it's an autonumber).

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the error you receive? The INSERT seems fine

Comment: @il_guru Visual basic just says 'Synatx error in INSET INTO statement but don't worry the issue has been resolved thanks to Remou.

Answer (score 5):

Password is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) and must be bracketed [password]

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], Email)
VALUES ('004606', 'Password', 'Email@Mail.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Reserved word is in [...]

```
INSERT INTO Users (Username, [Password], Email)
VALUES ('004606', 'Password', 'Email@Mail.com')
```